# Split string on colon in /bin/sh

Tags: shell, string, dash

My `dash` script takes a parameter in the form of `hostname:port`, i.e.:

```
myhost:1234
```

Whereas port is optional, i.e.:

```
myhost
```

I need to read the host and port into separate variables. In the first case, I can do:

```
HOST=${1%%:*}
PORT=${1##*:}
```

But that does not work in second case, when port was omitted; `echo ${1##*:}` simply returns hostname, instead of an empty string.

In Bash, I could do:

```
IFS=: read A B <<< asdf:111
```

But that does not work in `dash`.

Can I split string on `:` in dash, without invoking external programs (`awk`, `tr`, etc.)?

Comment: Make sure to split on the last colon if you want to support IPv6, and don't split on colons inside square brackets

Comment: @Ferrybig `%%` makes it greedy (as opposed to `%`), so it actually does this, at least in part; it would not work with `##`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just do:

```
case $1 in
  (*:*) host=${1%:*} port=${1##*:};;
  (*)   host=$1      port=$default_port;;
esac
```

You may want to change the `case $1` to `case ${1##*[]]}` to account for values of `$1` like `[::1]` (an IPv6 address without *port* part).

To split, you can use the *split+glob* operator (leave a parameter expansion unquoted) as that's what it's for after all:

```
set -o noglob # disable glob part
IFS=:         # split on colon
set -- $1     # split+glob

host=$1 port=${2:-$default_port}
```

(though that won't allow hostnames that contain a colon (like for that IPv6 address above)).

[That split+glob operator gets in the way and causes so much harm](/q/171346) the rest of the time that it would seem only fair that it be used whenever it's needed (though, I'll agree it's very cumbersome to use especially considering that POSIX `sh` has no support for local scope, neither for variables (`$IFS` here) nor for options (`noglob` here) (though `ash` and derivatives like `dash` are some of the ones that do (together with AT&T implementations of `ksh`, `zsh` and `bash` 4.4 and above)).

Note that `IFS=: read A B <<< "$1"` has a few issues of its own:

- you forgot the `-r` which means backslash will undergo some special processing.
- it would split `[::1]:443` into `[` and `:1]:443` instead of `[` and the empty string (for which you'd need `IFS=: read -r A B rest_ignored` or `[::1]` and `443` (for which you can't use that approach)
- it strips everything past the first occurrence of a newline character, so it can't be used with arbitrary strings (unless you use `-d ''` in `zsh` or `bash` and the data doesn't contain NUL characters, but then note that herestrings (or heredocs) do add an extra newline character!)
- in `zsh` (where the syntax comes from) and `bash`, here strings are implemented using temporary files, so it's generally less efficient than using `${x#y}` or split+glob operators.

Comment: In 2018, as a New Year's resolution, we should all stop writing scripts that will break with IPv6.

Comment: @Philippos too late by two weeks!

Comment: @RonJohn: Too late by two decades, somehow.

Answer (score 6):

Just remove the `:` in a separate statement; also, remove $host from the input to get the port:

```
host=${1%:*}
port=${1#"$host"}
port=${port#:}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another thought:

```
host=${1%:*}
port=${1##*:}
[ "$port" = "$1" ] && port=''
```

Answer (score 1):

A here string is just a syntactic shortcut for a single-line here document.

```
$ set myhost:1234
$ IFS=: read A B <<EOF
> $1
> EOF
$ echo "$A"
myhost
$ echo "B"
1234
```